# Rails exporting to CSV missing comma delimiter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-csv

I am exporting a custom array to a csv file. Everything is exporting correctly, however it is not adding a comma delimiter between each instance. What am I missing in my code to add this separation?

**data_services_controller**

```
def export_all
 @list = DataService.all
  respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render text: @list.to_csv }
end
end
```

**data_service.rb**

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << ["Data Product", "Requestor"]
  all.each do |dp|
    csv << [dp.name ,dp.requestor]
  end
end
end
```

**list.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Export to CSV", export_all_data_services_path(:format => :csv), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

@list.to_csv is calling the to_csv method on the relation returned by DataServive.all and not the class method you defined.

```
format.csv { render text: DataService.to_csv }
```

calls your to_csv class method. You won't need the @list instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have notice an wrong method calling in the controller, you can not call class method with an instance variable. You can rewrite the controller action as following and use `send_data` rather `render text`.

```
def export_all
    respond_to do |format|
     format.csv { send_data DataService.to_csv }
    end
end
```

And you already iterate all DataService in `to_csv` methods so I don't thing you need to query in `export_all` action. If you want to use `@list` any other purpose then you can use this.